# Forticlient VPN disallow navigation, can I modify this behaviour?

Tags: networking, vpn

For a customer, we need to make api call from vpn.
Developing, we connect using VPN
This works, and api calls works
But this vpn blocks every other ip different from api server.

Our development machine are all windows 10/11

Can I modify in someway routing to send via vpn only traffic to/from 10.10.0.0./16 ?

> We are developers, a third party. So we MUST be able to bypass the tunnel and use it ONLY for specific ips.

> I am not asking for anything illegal or violating company rules.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround

Every time the connection is estabilished, I do this

```
route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.254 metric 1
```

This overwrite the default route, forcing a very low metric to use it before the route added by FortiClient VPN.